# Simple Schema min rule is not giving error

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I am trying to update with $push and $inc at the same time , every thing is working fine but the problem is when I $inc my field with negative values its minimum value shouldn't be less that 0 as I have set the rule min in  my schema but it does not give an error set the field value in negative.

schema.js

```
mySchema=new SimpleSchema({
    "totalImages":{
        type:Number,
        min:0,
        optional:true,
    },
})
```

server.js

```
  jobOrders.update(
         {  
           orderNo:jobNo
        },
        {
           $push:{
                    //pushing an object in an array this is working as expected
                },
           $inc:{
                    totalImages:-2 //lets say the value of totalImages is 0 before, this should give an error since it will set negative value. But doesnot give any error. 
                }
        }
```

Comment: That seems like a bug Piysh.  I'd report it.